# change url for portfolio image

Tags: url-rewriting

I am working on champer theme , I add portfolio by guideness of documentation, but when i click on image , its go on another page, but I want to stay in similar page, not changing. how can I do this. i am wanted my portfolio Image behaviour like seo Optimization In this link. http://www.gallyapp.com/tf_themes/?theme=Chamber

my portfolio.php code is

```
      <?php
     session_start();

       if(!isset($hide_header) OR !$hide_header)
          {
      get_header();
           }

       if(isset($_SESSION['pp_portfolio_style']))
           {
         $pp_portfolio_style = $_SESSION['pp_portfolio_style'];
        }
        else
     {
$pp_portfolio_style = get_option('pp_portfolio_style');
       }

      if(empty($pp_portfolio_style))
      {
$pp_portfolio_style = '2';
       }

         include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/templates/template-portfolio-     ".$pp_portfolio_style.".php");

       ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you are looking at in the theme you mentioned is just a dummy link with #
That's why it just takes you to the start of the page. If you check the href attribute of the link for SEO Optimization it has # in the end.

http://www.gallyapp.com/tf_themes/chamber_wp/?page_id=11#

My suggestion is that you need to figure out where this link is being created and add target="_SELF" attribute to the hyperlink.

I hope it helps you out.